# Widget Dropdown doesn't working

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

Two days ago i had completes the wordpress version upgrade progress.  But after completes the update progress widget dropdown doesn't working properly,
I got the error message will be like this

> (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function)

and

> (TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined)

[image]